# Cannot pan image in zoomed ScrollView?

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I would like to build a simple view that allows me to show an image in a scroll view and let the user pinch to zoom on the image, and pan.

I've looked around and started with this`ScrollView`:

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            Image("test")
                .border(Color(.yellow))
        }
        .border(Color(.red))
        
    }
}
```

That would not handle zooming.

I then did this:

```
struct TestView: View {


    /// https://wp.usatodaysports.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/88/2014/03/sunset-in-the-dolos-mikadun.jpg
    var image = UIImage(named: "test")!
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var lastScaleValue: CGFloat = 1.0

    var body: some View {


        GeometryReader { geo in

            ScrollView([.vertical, .horizontal], showsIndicators: false){

                ZStack{

                    Image(uiImage: image)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.width)
                        .scaleEffect(scale)
                        .gesture(MagnificationGesture().onChanged { val in
                            let delta = val / self.lastScaleValue
                            self.lastScaleValue = val
                            var newScale = self.scale * delta
                            if newScale < 1.0 {
                                newScale =  1.0
                            }
                            scale = newScale
                        }.onEnded{val in
                            lastScaleValue = 1
                        })

                }

            }
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.width)
            .border(Color(.red))
            .background(Color(.systemBackground).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))

        }

    }

}
```

This allows me to zoom in and out, however, I cannot pan the image:

[image]

How can I code up things so I can support zoom and panning?

Comment: I might be missing it but in your code you are only scaling not rotating. You would have to add a variable for rotation. Just like you did scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to get the panning functionality you will have to change the size of your Image container, in this case the ZStack.
So first we need a variable to save the current latest scale value.

```
@State var scaledFrame: CGFloat = 1.0
```

Then just change the size of the container each time the gesture ends.

```
 ZStack{
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: geo.size.width )
            .scaleEffect(scale)
            .gesture(MagnificationGesture().onChanged { val in
                let delta = val / self.lastScaleValue
                self.lastScaleValue = val
                var newScale = self.scale * delta
                if newScale < 1.0 {
                    newScale =  1.0
                }
                scale = newScale
            }.onEnded{val in
                scaledFrame = scale//Update the value once the gesture is over
                lastScaleValue = 1
                
            })
            .draggable()
    }
    .frame(width: geo.size.width * scaledFrame, height: geo.size.width * scaledFrame)
    //change the size of the frame once the drag is complete
```

This is due to the way ScrollView works, when you were zooming in, the real size of the container was not changing, therefore the ScrollView was only moving accordingly.